# Laravel error page not showing when using virtual host

Tags: php, laravel, virtualhost

I install new laravel package through composer and everything is going fine  (including the error page) when I use `php artisan serve` and access my project in http://localhost:8000. But when I use virtual hosts (for example: example.dev), the error page is not showing, just a blank page. I'm not sure if it has something to do with my virtual host configuration because if the code has no error, the page just load normally. And I have changed the permission of storage and bootstrap/cache folder to 777.

Is there any other configuration that have to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which PHP version do you use on your server? Check the logs and see if you find something there.

Try giving the entire Laravel folder 755 permissions and then change the bootstrap/cache and storage folders.

Also try editing your .htaccess file, add something like:

```
RewriteEngine On RewriteBase /
```

Comment: I did your second suggestion, and the error page finally shown. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear mate. Good luck with your project, make something beautiful! :)